# how can i send a file from django into a script of python?

Tags: python, django, excel, mongodb, csv

I have a python script that processes an excel or csv document, in the python script I write the specific path of the file, locally.

this is my code in Python

```
''' url_rsso = r'file:///C:/Users/Mata/Desktop/RSSO.xlsx'


''' df_rsso = pd.read_excel(url_rsso)
```

this is my code in django

```
def upload(request):
context = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    df_rsso = request.FILES['document']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    name = fs.save(df_rsso.name, df_rsso)
    context['url'] = fs.url(name)

return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```

I also have a web page with django that is very simple, it has a ChooseFile, a button whose action will process the file and one to download the modified file.

What I want to do is:
the file that I store using django can send it to the script I have in python.

If the file is sent to the script, it processes it and exports it in excel which I have to send to django for the user to download the new modified file.

here is my  github https://github.com/mata-2p/codelweb

i am very new in python and django

Comment: Why not just add the script to your Django project and have it process every uploaded file? If it is an extensive process you could use asynchronous background workers as to not slow down your site while processing the task: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: I really thought about that solution, but the problem I have is to transform the file that is an .xlsx to a .csv in django, because the process is done with .csv for better data management.

Something the code does is make references to columns, rows, specific data, etc.

In the script I use pandas, numpy, datetime, etc.

I am trying to learn the documentation, because it is hard for me to apply how to make Django understand those codes.

Comment: I frequently use Pandas, XLSXwriter, etc in Django.

Comment: Now I am looking for ways to implement pandas and numpy in django.

Thanks for for your comments!